# Set headers using spring android resttemplate and android annotations

Tags: android, spring, rest, http-headers, resttemplate

I am currently playing with Spring Android Resttemplate to interact with a java-backed REST API. Actually, I am using [android annotations](http://androidannotations.org/) to send http calls to this back-end service and I must say it rocks. Basically, Android annotations allows you to define an interface for the service calls and the http methods to be used for each api call available : it will generate all the boiler-plate code related to low-level stuff like marshalling/unmarshalling, calling the right http method according to the interface definition.

Now, I would like to set some headers to http requests : How can I achieve this knowing that I only have a reference to the Service interface defining all the calls ?
I can also have reference to the RestTemplate object but it seems there is now way of setting the headers.

any help would really be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 3):

The way I approached it is by creating an instance of `ApiClient` in the application class and set a custom REST template.

In my case I was using Jackson for JSON message conversion:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(fac);
MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter =
        new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
converter.getObjectMapper().configure(Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
restTemplate
        .getMessageConverters()
        .add(converter);
mClient.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
```

My request factory `fac` then looks like this:

```
ClientHttpRequestFactory fac = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory() {

    @Override
    protected HttpUriRequest createHttpRequest(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri) {
        HttpUriRequest uriRequest = super.createHttpRequest(httpMethod, uri);
        // Add request headers
        uriRequest.addHeader(
                "Content-Type",
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        return uriRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientHttpRequest createRequest(URI uri, HttpMethod httpMethod)
            throws IOException {
        if (Config.DEBUG_REQUESTS) {
            Log.d(TAG, uri);
        }
        return super.createRequest(uri, httpMethod);
    }

};
```

### WARNING

Although this works on all Android devices in our office, **I've recently discovered that headers don't appear to be added with *all* devices!** I'm not sure why this is (or which devices specifically), but I'm looking in to it and will try to update this answer when I've found a resolution.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation : it is very interesting. I will try this and will let you know.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up using to get OAuth to work with Robospice